# Do you need this lawnmower part and what does it do?

Tags: small-engine, lawnmower

I have a craftsman riding lawnmower model 247.203744

I started it up and heard a sound that made a kind of plastic getting broken sound... which it was.

There is a black disk inside the engine compartment - that seems like a fan - that broke and started to get chewed up by the engine.  Nothing happened other than me starting the mower, putting the cluth in and changing it to reverse.

Picture of broken part:

[image]

Here is where it was before I took it out:

[image]

After I took it out:

[image]

So do I need this part, what is it, how do I get it back on if I need it?

Comment: You absolutely need this part as it's the fan which keeps the air cooled engine from getting too hot. How do you get it back on? Well, it looks like you need a new one (obviously). I really couldn't tell you from the pictures you've provided, but looks like you'd need to take the top off (the grated piece). I'm sure this isn't anything which you haven't already figured out.

Comment: @paulster2  - I can't figure out how that top comes off - will order a new part.

Comment: Having a really hard time finding this part.  Isn't part of the engine diagram.

Comment: Check on Sears' website ... they should have all the parts available for your Craftsman mower.

Comment: [Try this.](https://www.amazon.com/Briggs-Stratton-796084-FAN-FLYWHEEL/dp/B00PKEZ8HG)

Comment: Super glue and bi+carb powder...Probably work to fix it ...Google the bi carb part...